# Javascript: Grabbing the first element from a nested map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

For a two level map I'm using:

```
var first = function(){
    for(var one in map)
        for(var two in map[one])
            return map[one][two];
    }
```

is there an easier way? Possibly something along the lines of

```
map.first()
```

?

Comment: Object properties aren't ordered by definition, so I don't think you should make assumptions about it; though, `map[Object.keys(map)[0]]` would be the replacement.

Comment: @Jack - random is fine, thanks didn't know about `Object.keys()`

Comment: It's not exactly random either :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really getting what you're trying to do, but the easiest way to handle nested structures with an unknown depth is recursion:

```
var getWhatever = function(obj)
{
  if( isWhatever(obj) ) {
    return obj;
  }
  for( var field in obj ) {
    return getWhatever( obj[field] );
  }
};
```